# Using the Zip task in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I have been attempting to use the zip task of msbuild in a project I am working on at the moment.

My project file looks something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup> <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(SolutionDir)\.build</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath> </PropertyGroup> 

<Import Project="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />

<ItemGroup>
<FileToZip include="C:\FilePath"></FilesToZip>
<FileToZip include="C:\FilePath"></FilesToZip>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="BeforeBuild">

<PropertyGroup>
<ReleasePath>\releasepath</ReleasePath>
```

```
<Zip Files="@(FilesToZip)" WorkingDirectory="$(ReleasePath)" ZipFileName="HTMLeditor.html" ZipLevel="9" />

</Target>
```

However, the zip file updates but does not contain the files specified in the item group FilesToZip. I cannot figure out why they aren't being recognised! I have double checked file paths and they are correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any log produced in console by zip task? Try printing @(FilesToZip) using the Message task to make sure Items are included properly

Comment: Haven't tried printing the log to console but looks like i am going to have to in order to debug what's going on. Thanks

Comment: There are several errors in your target code, first you have: `<FileToZip ...></FilesToZip>`, is that a typo?  Also, having a declaration of the same variable twice does not mean you get an array with both values, it means you get the last value you declared.  So in your sample (assuming its mostly correct) you would have a `$(FileToZip)` that yielded `C:\FilePath`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo yes. The C:\FilePath is in place to mimic a filepath it isn't the real one. The real ones are both different. One leads to the scripts folder at the root level the project and the other to a html page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FileToZip include="C:\FilePath;C:\FilePath"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

As I mentioned in my comment, simply creating a variable (`FileToZip`) and repeating it twice with different values does not give you an array that contains both of the values.  You end up with only the last value (and not an array at all).  Your `include` attribute is a selector which is used to build the array and it can contain multiple values, wildcards and other patterns which are used to build out that array for you.

Here's a link to MSDN that gives you more information on how to use the `Include` attribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171454.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help. Shall try this first thing in the morning and let you know if it has worked. Thanks again.

Comment: actually, original declaration (given, the typo is corrected) is also perfectly fine. Items are not overridden, but appended. Eg.g. this is what vs uses in csproj files: `<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="BaseContext.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BaseMigration.cs" /> <ItemGroup>`

Answer (score 0):

I ditched the ItemGroup in the end, and went with another way of doing it.

```
<Target Name="Zip"> 

<CreateItem Include="FilesToInclude" >          

<Output ItemName="ZipFiles" TaskParameter="Include"/>
```

```
<Zip ZipFileName="ZipFile.zip" WorkingDirectory="FolderToWriteZipTo" Files="@(ZipFiles)" /> 

</Target>
```

This method seemed to be easier and wasn't adding files to the root of the file.

Thanks for the help though guys.